# ORA-01427 "Single-row subquery returns more than one row" with TWO CASES [Oracle DB]

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having an issue with the following query and unable to figured out where I'm wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM TBLCUSTCHANNELACCT b WHERE
 (CASE WHEN NVL('0001, 0015', '-1') = '-1' THEN NVL('0001, 0015', '-1')
      ELSE b.productid END
         IN
  CASE WHEN NVL('0001, 0015', '-1') = '-1' THEN NVL('0001, 0015', '-1') 
      ELSE
   (SELECT a.product_id FROM tblcfgproductdetail a WHERE a.productcode IN ('0001', '0015') )
END);
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: You have a `case` that can return the result of a query; that query is returning more than one record, so `case` can't handle it. Why `NVL('0001, 0015', '-1')`? Is it only for testing?

Comment: @Aleksej Really Thanks, so is there any workaround?, if I put only one value like " a.productcode IN ('0001')  ", then it works fine...

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result; this will help us in understanding your needs.

Comment: The use of `CASE` in a `where` clause is almost always a misstep. `CASE` should be reserved for places where logical conditions are not natively support (such as a column definition).

Comment: @Aleksej Yes NVL('0001, 0015', '-1') is only for testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `case`.  Just use basic logic:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM TBLCUSTCHANNELACCT b
WHERE ('0001, 0015' IS NULL) OR
      b.productid IN (SELECT a.product_id
                      FROM tblcfgproductdetail a
                      WHERE a.productcode IN ('0001', '0015')
                     );
```

I'm pretty sure this is the intention of your query.